# Android set specific time and at Alarmmanager

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I want to set specific time and date in Alarm Manager.I have try to set time in calendar. But after run the application it sends the email properly on specific date but not send specific time whatever i have to set in Alarm Manager.Can someone help me please.Thanks in advance.

Here is my Alarm Manager code

```
btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
     btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {       
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                     cal.setTime(emailDate);
                     cal.set(Calendar.PM, 5);
                     cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 5);
                     cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                     Date dt = cal.getTime();
                     Long longDate = (long) dt.getTime();
                     System.out.println("dt :=" + dt);
                     System.out.println("Long Date :=" + longDate);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
                     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Xyz.this, 1, intent, 0);
                     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, longDate, pendingIntent);
           }
}
```

Here is AlarmManager Code

```
      strMinusDate = "22-08-2014";
      String[] splitDate_Parts = strMinusDate.split("-");
      saparated_Day = splitDate_Parts[0];
      saparated_Month = splitDate_Parts[1];
      saparated_Year = splitDate_Parts[2];

     int convertDay = Integer.valueOf(saparated_Day);
     int convertMonth = Integer.valueOf(saparated_Month);
     int convertYear =  Integer.valueOf(saparated_Year); 
     cal.set(convertDay,convertMonth,convertYear,11,30,00);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Xyz.this, 1, intent, 0);
     AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
     alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Here is AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver class code.

```
public class AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    String strServiceName;
    String strSuppliername;
    String strEmail;
    String strReplacementDate;
    String strIntervalDays;
    String strNextReplacementDate;
    String strEmailDate;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context con, Intent arg1)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         SharedPreferences prefs = con.getSharedPreferences("MyPref_Email", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

         strServiceName=prefs.getString("ServiceName",null);
         strSuppliername=prefs.getString("Suppliername" , null);
         strEmail=prefs.getString("Email" , null);
         strReplacementDate=prefs.getString("ReplacementDate" , null);
         strIntervalDays=prefs.getString("IntervalDays" , null);
         strNextReplacementDate=prefs.getString("NextReplacementDate" ,null);
         strEmailDate = prefs.getString("EmailDate", null);

         System.out.println(strServiceName+" , "+strSuppliername+" , "+strEmail+" , "+strReplacementDate+" , "+strIntervalDays+" , "+strNextReplacementDate);


         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strServiceName);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strSuppliername);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strEmail);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strReplacementDate);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strIntervalDays);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strNextReplacementDate);
         Log.e("ON CREATE" , "=" + strEmailDate);


         String subject =strServiceName;
         System.out.println(" subject  = " + subject); 


        String body = strServiceName
                      +","
                      +strSuppliername
                      +","
                      +strEmail
                      +","
                      +strReplacementDate
                      +","
                      +strIntervalDays
                      +","
                      +strNextReplacementDate
                      +","
                      +strEmailDate;

                      Log.e("body " , " = " + body);
        System.out.println(" body  = " + body); 


                      Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                      shareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                      shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{strEmail});
                      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                      shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , body);
                      Intent new_intent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via");
                      new_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); 
                      con.startActivity(new_intent);
                      Log.e("Send Email ="," In My Service  ");
                      System.out.println("Service start time");

    }

}
```

Comment: Whats happening to SO, dumb people downvote good questions without a comment.

Comment: @Siddharth : What are you trying to say ?

Comment: Someone downvoted your question without a comment. I just upvoted it.

Comment: @Robotics research more about Receivers in android,you are missing out basic points which shows that you don't know enough about them.

Answer (score 1):

Some **ACTION(event)** needs to be fired by the sender so that the `receiver` wakes up in response to that particular event. You are not providing any event in the `intent` which you are firing

```
//set the time in this way by giving proper values
    calendar.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay,selectedHour, selectedMinute);

//create the AlarmManager in this way using that calender object
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC,
calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

EDIT :

When creating `intent`in your `AlarmManager` code ,

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.abc.pqr"); //just a user defined action
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Xyz.this, 1, myIntent, 0);
```

In manifest add :

```
  <permission android:name="com.abc.pqr"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.abc.pqr" />
```

in `<application>` tag, add

```
<receiver
    android:name="yourFullPackagePath.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver"                     
    android:enabled="true" >
      <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.abc.pqr" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: - Email is send but not show in inbox why .I have to change in my code whatever you have said to me . Like this = cal.set(convertDay,convertMonth,convertYear,18,01,0);

Comment: the alarm manager is working properly. there's some other problem with your code

Comment: @ Sam Dunk: I mean to say why not Alarm notify to me at 06:01 PM

Comment: paste the code of AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver here

Comment: I'm talking about the code in file  AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java

Comment: :- Sorry for mistake.Just a minute I have post again.

Comment: are you listing out the receiver in the manifest file and it's intent filter properly?

Comment: :- I post my AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java code above.Please see above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59786/discussion-between-robotics-and-sam-dunk).

Comment: I don't understand what are you saying about Intent myIntent = new Intent("com.abc.pqr")  <action android:name="com.abc.pqr" ;<permission android:name="com.abc.pqr"></permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.abc.pqr" />

Comment: what is 'com.abc.pqr'.